# Passing data from Views laravel 4.2

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-blade

I do some calculations in the controller, and pass the data to my view like this.

```
return View::make('fend.clist', compact('detail_'));
```

From this view controller "fend.clist" I'd like to open another view (blade) along with the 'detail_' variable which basically has some data that I need to show there. I tried POSTing it, but I wasn't able to recieve the data completely. 
How else can I pass data from one view to another view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using the sessions, first put:

`Session::put(['name'=>'value']);`

Then get:

`Session::get('name');`

Answer (score 0):

You must nest sub-view to view and pass data to sub-view.

```
return View::make('fend.clist')->nest('fend.detail', compact('detail_'));
```

More info in [docs](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/responses#views)